# How to debug the error "Implicit conversion from datatype 'X' to 'Y' is not allowed"?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While running the below query, I am getting error for field `error_num`:

```
Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed. 
Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Below is the query

```
select top 100"Insert into KLG_TRN_SCE..dbBatchRequest values ('" 
 + comp_nr
+"','"
+ ssn_nr
+"','"
+ convert(char(10),Version,101)
+"','"
+ plan_nr
+"','1"
+"','"
+ CAST(LEFT(error_num, 4) AS int)
+"',"
+ error_txt
+"',"
+ addname
+"',"
+ convert(char(10),adddate,101)
+"')"
From KLG_TRN_SCE..dcErrorBin
Where ssn_nr='603761193'
```

Comment: Neither `convert(char(10),Version,101)` nor concatenation via `+` nor `KLG_TRN_SCE..dcErrorBin` is valid Oracle syntax. Consult Oracle SQL documentation.

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find `top 100` or the `convert()` function? Also `KLG_TRN_SCE..dcErrorBin` is an invalid identifier in SQL.

Comment: error you're getting suggest it is not oracle. please change tags

Comment: How get the result of the below scenario:- suppose a participant is getting terminated in oct. So i want to get this into report on the base of the logic" end day of the month plus 30 days" measn any particpant who is getting termed on 8 or 9 oct then it should come on the report after end day of the  oct + 30 days i.e. 30Nov

Comment: pretty sure oracle string concat is `||` not `+`  + is reserved for math while || is for string concatenation. + use chr(39) for your single quotes.  Pretty sure " are used for defining field names while ' for string.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to use Sybase or T-SQL against an oracle database.  The syntax between databases vary slightly especially around dates, string concat, and string parsing.

So are you looking for execution against Oracle or another database?  if oracle, the below should be close.

I'm not sure what you meant by version or what formats you wanted the dates to be in, but this seems to run.  I used a with (Common table expression) to stage some data to ensure it ran after all the changes.

So your issues:

1. No such thing as top we could limit by a `rowNum < 101`; but an order by should be used
2. in oracle `||` is operator for string concat not `+`
3. `convert(char(10),Version,101)` you appear to believe is a date but this is not true in oracle unless version is a field with a date... in which case `to_date(version,'DD/MM/YYYY')` may be desired?
4. quotes `"`are used for field notation much like `[]` are in T-SQL so to build a dynamic insert, I concat chr(39).
5. `CAST(LEFT(error_num, 4) AS int)` is invalid you need to use `substr(error_num, 1,4)` in oracle
6. `convert(char(10),adddate,101)` is invalid in Oracle perhaps you mean `to_date(adddate,'MM/DD/YYYY')`

.

```
with dcErrorBin(comp_nr, ssn_nr, version,plan_nr, error_num, error_txt,Addname,adddate) as 
(Select 1,'603761193',(SELECT WM_CONCAT(BANNER) FROM V$VERSION),'Three','1234-hello','Error_txt','AddName',sysdate from dual)

SELECT
'Insert into KLG_TRN_SCE..dbBatchRequest values (' || chr(39)
|| comp_nr||Chr(39)
||','
|| chr(39)||ssn_nr||Chr(39)
||','
|| chr(39)||replace(Version,',','~~') || chr(39)
||','
|| chr(39)||plan_nr||Chr(39)
||',1'
||','
|| CAST(substr(error_num,1,4) AS int)
||','
|| chr(39)||error_txt||Chr(39)
||','
|| chr(39)||addname||chr(39)
||','
|| 'to_date('||chr(39)||adddate||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||'DD-MON-YY'||chr(39)||')'
||')'
FROM dcErrorBin
WHERE ssn_nr='603761193'
  and rowNum <= 100
ORDER BY ADDDate Desc;  --Perhaps order by add date desc so you get most recent errors?
```

RESULTED IN:

```
Insert into KLG_TRN_SCE..dbBatchRequest values 
('1'
, '603761193'
, 'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
   ~~PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
   ~~CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production
   ~~TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
   ~~NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production'
, 'Three'
, 1
, 1234
, 'Error_txt'
, 'AddName'
, to_date('14-DEC-16','DD-MON-YY'))
```

The inserts would error out if

1. I'm using the wrong date formats
2. don't have the proper values wrapped in tics
3. error_num's 1st 4 characters are not numeric.